# Bitbucket Pipeline - Fails to build Quarkus native image (Out of Memory)

Tags: quarkus, bitbucket-pipelines, graalvm

I am trying to setup a Bitbucket Pipeline for building a native Quarkus image of my app, but the build fails with

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Image generation failed. Exit code was 137 which indicates an out of memory error. Consider increasing the Xmx value for native image generation by setting the "quarkus.native.native-image-xmx" property

I have increased the size of the pipeline touse double amount of memory (8 GB instead of 4 GB) and tried to give docker more memory, but without any success. I have changed the database layer from mongodb to postgres. After that change the build fails with mentioned error. My `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: Build Native Image
          image: quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:21.2-java11
          services:
            - docker
          size: 2x
          caches:
            - maven
          script:
            - ./mvnw package -Pnative
          artifacts:
            - target/*-runner

definitions:
  service:
    docker:
      memory: 7128
```

Can I set other parameters to assign more memory to the build?

Comment: Can you try setting `-Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=5GB`?

Answer (score 1):

Graalvm will grab as much memory as it can get access to and sometimes that his the outer limit. Thus even if you give it more it will keep failing.

Thus it might be a question of actually constraining the JVM so graalvm will start garbage collecting sooner.

You do that setting `-Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=5GB` as suggested by the error message and @geoand.